# How to run a coroutine inside a context?

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, coroutine, python-contextvars

[In the Python docs about Context Vars](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html) a Context::run method is described to enable executing a callable inside a context so changes that the callable perform to the context are contained inside the copied Context. Though what if you need to execute a coroutine? What are you supposed to do in order to achieve the same behavior?

In my case, what I wanted was something like this to handle a transactional context with possible nested transactions:

```py
my_ctxvar = ContextVar("my_ctxvar")

async def coro(func, transaction):
    token = my_ctxvar.set(transaction)
    r = await func()
    my_ctxvar.reset(token)  # no real need for this, but why not either
    return r

async def foo():
    ctx = copy_context()
    # simplification to one case here: let's use the current transaction if there is one
    if tx_owner := my_ctxvar not in ctx:
        tx = await create_transaction()
    else:
        tx = my_ctxvar.get()
    
    try:
        r = await ctx.run(coro)  # not actually possible
        if tx_owner:
            await tx.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        if tx_owner:
            await tx.rollback()
        raise from e
    return r
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I already pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63131230/13782669), `context variables` are natively supported by `asyncio` and are ready to be used without any extra configuration.
It should be noted that:

- Сoroutines executed by the current task by means of `await` **share the same** context
- New spawned tasks by `create_task` are executed in the **copy** of parent task context.

Therefore, in order to execute a coroutine in a copy of the current context, you can execute it as a task:

```py
await asyncio.create_task(coro())
```

Small example:

```py
import asyncio
from contextvars import ContextVar

var = ContextVar('var')


async def foo():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print(f"var inside foo {var.get()}")
    var.set("ham")  # change copy


async def main():
    var.set('spam')
    await asyncio.create_task(foo())
    print(f"var after foo {var.get()}")


asyncio.run(main())
```

```
var inside foo spam
var after foo spam
```

Comment: Is there any way to override this behavior? That is, to manually pass a context into a subtask so that the subtask can modify it's parent's context?

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible and you need to use some kind of synchronization  or shared variable

Comment: I think I figured out how to do it. I posted a separate question where I made it explicit that I _want_ the behavior of sharing a context between tasks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68639982/copying-contexvars-context-between-tasks?noredirect=1#comment121330845_68639982