# Copying contexvars.Context between tasks

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, python-contextvars

I have a program (an ASGI server) that is structured roughly like this:

```py
import asyncio
import contextvars

ctxvar = contextvars.ContextVar("ctx")


async def lifepsan():
    ctxvar.set("spam")


async def endpoint():
    assert ctxvar.get() == "spam"


async def main():
    ctx = contextvars.copy_context()
    task = asyncio.create_task(lifepsan())
    await task
    task = asyncio.create_task(endpoint())
    await task

asyncio.run(main())
```

Because the lifespan event / endpoints are run in tasks, they can't share contextvars.
This is by design: tasks *copy* the context before executing, so `lifespan` can't set `ctxvar` properly.
This is the desired behavior for endpoints, but I would like for execution to appear like this (from a user's perspective):

```py
async def lifespan():
    ctxvar.set("spam")
    await endpoint()
```

In other words, the endpoints are executed in their own independent context, but within the context of the lifespan.

I tried to get this to work by using `contextlib.copy_context()`:

```py
import asyncio
import contextvars

ctxvar = contextvars.ContextVar("ctx")


async def lifepsan():
    ctxvar.set("spam")
    print("set")


async def endpoint():
    print("get")
    assert ctxvar.get() == "spam"


async def main():
    ctx = contextvars.copy_context()
    task = ctx.run(asyncio.create_task, lifepsan())
    await task
    endpoint_ctx = ctx.copy()
    task = endpoint_ctx.run(asyncio.create_task, endpoint())
    await task

asyncio.run(main())
```

As well as:

```py
async def main():
    ctx = contextvars.copy_context()
    task = asyncio.create_task(ctx.run(lifespan))
    await task
    endpoint_ctx = ctx.copy()
    task = asyncio.create_task(endpoint_ctx.run(endpoint))
    await task
```

However it seems that `contextvars.Context.run` does not work this way (I guess the context is bound when the coroutine is created but not when it is executed).

Is there a simple way to achieve the desired behavior, without restructuring how the tasks are being created or such?

Comment: This is how context variables should work, if you want two coroutines to share the same value of variable you can try to use some key:value storage, e.g. ordinary dictionary.

Comment: With full control over everything, that would make sense. The larger context for this is a situation is a library which we'll call *B*. *B* is called by another library *A*, which is the one doing the task scheduling and such (hence why I said "without restructuring how the tasks are being created). In turn, *B* calls user code. Users may want to use context variables, or even use a library which in turn is using context variables. The goal here was to enable reasonable behavior for users without requiring the users of *A* to modify their code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature will be supported in Python 3.11: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/91150

You will be able to write:

```py
async def main():
    ctx = contextvars.copy_context()
    task = asyncio.create_task(lifepsan(), context=ctx)
    await task
    endpoint_ctx = ctx.copy()
    task = asyncio.create_task(endpoint(), context=endpoint_ctx)
    await task
```

In the meantime, in current Python versions you will need a backport of this feature. I can't think of a good one, but a bad one is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/91150#issuecomment-1137074675).

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I came up with, inspired by [PEP 555](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0555/#id10) and [asgiref](https://github.com/django/asgiref/blob/213ee0fb5727cbd658e1a3bb305c31c7c677c771/asgiref/sync.py#L22-L30):

```py
from contextvars import Context, ContextVar, copy_context
from typing import Any


def _set_cvar(cvar: ContextVar, val: Any):
    cvar.set(val)


class CaptureContext:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.context = Context()

    def __enter__(self) -> "CaptureContext":
        self._outer = copy_context()
        return self

    def sync(self):
        final = copy_context()
        for cvar in final:
            if cvar not in self._outer:
                # new contextvar set
                self.context.run(_set_cvar, cvar, final.get(cvar))
            else:
                final_val = final.get(cvar)
                if self._outer.get(cvar) != final_val:
                    # value changed
                    self.context.run(_set_cvar, cvar, final_val)

    def __exit__(self, *args: Any):
        self.sync()


def restore_context(context: Context) -> None:
    """Restore `context` to the current Context"""
    for cvar in context.keys():
        try:
            cvar.set(context.get(cvar))
        except LookupError:
            cvar.set(context.get(cvar))
```

Usage:

```py
import asyncio
import contextvars

ctxvar = contextvars.ContextVar("ctx")


async def lifepsan(cap: CaptureContext):
    with cap:
        ctxvar.set("spam")


async def endpoint():
    assert ctxvar.get() == "spam"


async def main():
    cap = CaptureContext()
    await asyncio.create_task(lifepsan(cap))
    restore_context(cap.context)
    task = asyncio.create_task(endpoint())
    await task

asyncio.run(main())
```

The `sync()` method is provided in case the task is long-running and you need to capture the context before it finishes. A somewhat contrived example:

```py
import asyncio
import contextvars

ctxvar = contextvars.ContextVar("ctx")


async def lifepsan(cap: CaptureContext, event: asyncio.Event):
    with cap:
        ctxvar.set("spam")
        cap.sync()
        event.set()
        await asyncio.sleep(float("inf"))


async def endpoint():
    assert ctxvar.get() == "spam"


async def main():
    cap = CaptureContext()
    event = asyncio.Event()
    asyncio.create_task(lifepsan(cap, event))
    await event.wait()
    restore_context(cap.context)
    task = asyncio.create_task(endpoint())
    await task

asyncio.run(main())
```

I think it would still be much nicer if `contextvars.Context.run` worked with coroutines.