# Difference between await Coroutine and await Task

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, fastapi, aioredis

On FastAPI, I have an endpoint that calls `get_1` or `get_2` coroutine function below.

`get_1` uses `await redis.get(key)`

`get_2` uses `await asyncio.ensure_future(redis.get(key))`

Is there any difference between the 2 functions in terms of functionality and performance?

```
#redis.py

import asyncio
import aioredis

async def get_1(key):
   redis = aioredis.from_url("redis://localhost")
   value = await redis.get(key)
   return value

async def get_2(key):
   redis = aioredis.from_url("redis://localhost")
   value = await asyncio.ensure_future(redis.get(key))
   return value
```

Comment: I suspect that `get_2()` is much older code.  The async framework has become cleaner with each release of Python.  `asyncio.ensure_future` is a low-level API and should probably shouldn't need to use it in most code anymore.

Comment: I agree with newer Python, `get_2()` should use `asyncio.create_task`. Then I still have the same question.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, to understand what exactly `await` does and how `task` differs from `future`, I recommend starting with this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49005651/how-does-asyncio-actually-work) and, of course, official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html).

As for your question, at first glance, the both expressions `await coro()` and `await create_task(coro())` do the same thing. They start coroutine, wait for it to complete and return the result.

But there are a number of important difference:

- The `await coro()` leads to direct call to the coroutine code without returning execution path to event loop. This issue was explained in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63455683/when-is-asyncios-default-scheduler-fair/).
- The `await create_task(coro())` leads to wrapping the coroutine in a [task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#creating-tasks), scheduling its execution in the event loop, returning execution path to event
  loop and then waiting for the result. In this case, before executing of the target coroutine(scheduled as a task) other already sheduled tasks can be executed.
  Usually, `await` is not used with `create_task`, to allow a spawned task to run in parallel, but sometimes it is needed, the example in the next paragraph
- The `await coro()` executes the target coroutine within the current [context](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html) of variables, and the `await create_task(coro())` within the copy of the current context (more details in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64988557/how-to-run-a-coroutine-inside-a-context/64989815)).

Based on the above, most likely you want `await coro()`, leaving the second expression for more specific cases.

Comment: About the 2nd point:  I think `await create_task(coro())` creates a task and **immediately** wait for it, thus **should block the execution** the same way that the 1st point does. Your explanation means `other already scheduled tasks can be executed` under `await create_task(coro())`. I wonder if there is any reference to support this 2nd point?

Comment: Of course, excerpt from the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task): *[Task is] a future-like object. [...] Event loops use cooperative scheduling: an event loop runs one Task at a time. While a Task awaits for the completion of a Future, the event loop **runs other Tasks**, callbacks, or performs IO operations.*

Comment: I'd like to have an argument. The excerpt explains when a `coro()` of a Task is waiting for something, the event loop takes back control and can run another `coro()` of another Task. It doesn't explain what happen at `await create_task(coro())`, i.e, when `create_task` (1) and `await` (2) occur together. Your 2nd point says in a _very short period of time_ between (1) and (2), the event loop **can** take back control to run something else. My suspicion is that the event loop **can't** take back control between (1) and (2), because maybe the _very short period of time_ is like 0?

Comment: The key point is that the event loop does not take control by itself, tasks give it over when they see fit. In particular, `await task` will certainly transfer control to the event loop, there is no place for time races here.